# How to show People menu in Admin for role restricted user?

Tags: users

Created role "tech support" for help desk to address user account issues.

Granted this role the following privs:

```
Administration
  Access administration menu

User
  Administer permissions
  Administer users
  View user profiles
  Change own username
  Cancel own user account
  Select method for cancelling own account
```

The Administration menu does not display for the user - I see the home icon and nothing else.  I did enable clear cache just to see something will display and it does.

Yet if I go to /admin/people, the user with this role can perform the actions I desire.  My issue is simply displaying the People menu item.

Any thoughts/pointers?  This is a production environment, I need to be able to do this without adding new modules to the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to grant them "Use the administration pages and help"